# puzzle of comparing string with numeric value to integer in python if statement

Tags: python, string

I thought when comparing a int to a string (with a numeric value) in python, it is not necessary to explicitly convert the string. But the following code taught me a lesson:

```
size = raw_input("a numeric value:")
a_str = 'abcdefghijklmn'
if len(a_str) > size:
    print("The string is longer.")
elif len(a_str) < size:
    print("The string is shorter.")
else:
    print("they are equal in length.")
```

No matter what value I typed in, it always chose len(a_str) < size until I convert the size using int(size).

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 2):

python [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) clearly mentioned that

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.
>
> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and
>   different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered
>   consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array
>   yields a consistent result). Furthermore, some types (for example,
>   file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any
>   two objects of that type are unequal. Again, such objects are ordered
>   arbitrarily but consistently. The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise
>   a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.

Related question:

[How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)